# Windowsのファイル名変更で、画像の拡張子をpngからjpgへ変更して保存したら画像が表示されたのですが、なぜですか？

Tags: 画像

**やりたいこと**
png画像をjpg画像へ変換したい

**従来取っていた方法**
画像編集ソフトウェアでpng画像ファイルを開き、jpg画像として保存していました

**今回試した方法**
Windowsのファイル名変更で、画像の拡張子をpngからjpgへ変更して保存。
その保存したファイルを画像ソフトウェアで開いたら画像が表示されました。

**質問**
・ファイル名変更で、「拡張子をjpgへ変更した後、表示された画像」は、jpg画像ですか？
・この変換方法は正しいですか？
・もしこの方法が正しいのなら、バッチやPHPなどで、ファイルの拡張子変更するだけで、画像変換できるのですか？

Comment: その拡張子を変更したら表示されたという画像ソフトウェアが何かというのと、変更する前は同じソフトウェアで表示できていたのかどうか、それから例えば質問記事にアップロードしても問題無い対象ファイルを張り付けるとか、を追記してみてはどうでしょう。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ・ファイル名変更で、「拡張子をjpgへ変更した後、表示された画像」は、jpg画像ですか？

pngを拡張子jpgに変えただけでは、拡張子がjpgのpngフォーマットの画像です。
表示出来るかどうかは、画像ビューワーの実装によると思います。ファイルヘッダを解析して表示するタイプなら、拡張子は見ていないと思います。

> ・この変換方法は正しいですか？

そもそも変換されていません。バイナリエディタでファイルを開いてヘッダを見たら判ります。
[pngのシグネチャ](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=png&mode=EXT)
[jpgのシグネチャ](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?search=jpg&mode=EXT)

> ・もしこの方法が正しいのなら、バッチやPHPなどで、ファイルの拡張子変更するだけで、
> 画像変換できるのですか？

出来ません。

Comment: なるほど、(拡張子を考慮せず)ファイルヘッダだけを見て判断する画像ビューワーもあるわけですね