# .8a3nFK拡張子で表示された画像のファイル形式を知りたい

Tags: 画像

#### 一番知りたいこと

下記リンク先に表示されている(元の)画像ファイル形式を知りたい
[画像リンク](https://gardenplace.actiombot.com/#/imgPage?imgURL=https:%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Factiombot-bucket%2F$2a$08$VyYesY.CJ10klUWIYBzSlu6MTgt72F69GE7d5xzZqKLBkl.8a3nFK)

#### 試したこと

ダウンロードしたファイル拡張子を、取り敢えずjpgへ変更してみたら画像表示されました(が最適かどうかは分かりません)。

#### その他疑問 (できれば知りたいこと)

- 拡張子「.8a3nFK」なのに、どうして画像表示されるのですか？
- 「storage.googleapis.com」の記述がありますが、Google APIへリクエストを投げ、返ってきた画像データを表示しているのですか？
  もしそうだとしても拡張子が「.8a3nFK」な理由が分かりません。動的に処理しているから？

Comment: 参考までに、ブラウザ(Firefox)で「画像の情報を表示」を行なうと 「MIMEタイプ: PNG画像」と表示されます。また、レスポンスヘッダを見ると `content-type: application/octet-stream` となっています(バイナリデータ)。

Comment: Firefoxでは「MIMEタイプ: PNG画像」と表示されるのですね。Chromeで確認してみたら「octet-stream」は確認できたのですが、「MIMEタイプ」確認の仕方は分かりませんでした。

Comment: 重複候補: [Windowsのファイル名変更で、画像の拡張子をpngからjpgへ変更して保存したら画像が表示されたのですが、なぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71679/3060)

Comment: 末尾付近にたまたまドットが含まれているけど、よく見るとそれより前にもドットがあるので拡張子というわけではないのかなと思います。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

リンク先のファイルをダンプすると、
89 50 4E 47
で始まっています。
したがってこれはPNGファイルです。

Comment: 追記
たぶんですが、jpgへ変更して表示されたのは、jpgへ変更したことでjpgに関連付けしているビューアーが起動→ビューアーはファイルのマジックコードを見てPNGだと判定して表示した、ということなのかなと思います。ブラウザも然り、かな？

Comment: 「リンク先のファイルをダンプすると」。なるほど、結局はその方法が一番確実なのですね。

Answer (score 6):

現代のブラウザは、拡張子によってファイルのフォーマット(メディア種別)を判別しません。

- [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) - MDN

> `Content-Type` エンティティヘッダーは、リソースの[メディア種別](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Glossary/MIME_type)を示すために使用します。
> (中略)
> `Content-Type` ヘッダーはクライアントに返されたコンテンツが実際にはどのような種類のものであるかを伝えます。

(今回の質問からは逸れますが、)ただし、続く説明に

> 場合によってはブラウザーは MIME を推定し、このヘッダーの値に従わないこともあります。

とある通り、過去のブラウザでは拡張子によってメディア種別を判別することもありました。次のリンクで解説されています。

- [IEのMIME Sniffing](https://boscono.hatenablog.com/entry/20070805/p1) - てきとうなメモ

ちなみに今回の`Content-Type`は`application/octet-stream`であり、これが`<img>`の`src`に指定されています。
従って具体的な画像フォーマットの判定が必要ですが、pngであるかどうかは、他の回答にある通り、 `0x89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` で始まっているかでチェックするようです。

- [MIME Sniffing > 6.1. 画像型パタンとの照合](https://triple-underscore.github.io/mimesniff-ja.html#matching-an-image-type-pattern)

  - [原文](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matching-an-image-type-pattern)

---

質問文中のURLに含まれる文字列

```
$2a$08$VyYesY.CJ10klUWIYBzSlu6MTgt72F69GE7d5xzZqKLBkl.8a3nFK
```

ですが、文字列パターンから見てbcryptハッシュ化の結果値と思われます。

- [BCrypt(Blowfish暗号)について調べたので文書化してみました](https://yuskamiya.tumblr.com/post/100503173956/bcrypt-blowfish) - Kamiya::Memo
- [bcrypt](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) - Wikipedia

つまり、 `.8a3nFK` は拡張子を意図した文字列というわけではないでしょう。