# 拡張子と動画ファイルの関係性について。MP4ファイル拡張子を.MOVへ変更後、ソフトウェアで読み込んだらどうなりますか？

Tags: 動画

MP4ファイルの拡張子を.MOVへ変更後、ソフトウェアで読み込んだらどうなりますか？

- ソフトウェアはこのファイルをMP4ファイルとして読み込みますか？
- それともMOVファイルとして読み込みますか？
- あるいは、ソフトウェアの実装により異なる？

質問経緯
SDカードが正常に読み込めなくなったため、データ復旧ソフトウェアを使用しました。
その結果、「.SR2ファイル」や「.MOVファイル」ができました。
それぞれ元のファイルは「.ARWファイル」や「.MP4ファイル」だと思われるのですが、ファイル拡張子だけを間違えて復元したのか、あるいは、本当に「.SR2ファイル」や「.MOVファイル」へ変換して復元したのかが分かりません。
拡張子以外から動画ファイル形式を確認する方法はありますか？
復元された「.MOVファイル」と、そのファイル拡張子を「.MP4ファイル」へ変更したファイルのいずれもソフトウェアで再生されたのですが、「.MOVファイル」として再生されたのか「.MP4ファイル」として再生されたのかが分かりません。

Comment: 「.MOVファイルの拡張子を.MOVへ変更した後のファイルを読み込むのに用いるソフトウェアは何ですか？」
どんなソフトウェアを使ったのか、という基本的な情報を含んでいない質問に、正しい(と質問者が思っている）回答が返ってくることを期待するのは無理があるとおもいませんか。

Comment: 過去の類似質問 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/75604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

動画ファイルを含むバイナリファイルの多くは、ファイルの先頭部分でそのファイル形式の特徴を表すようなデータ (文字列) が含まれており、復旧ツール等もこれらのデータを頼りに元のファイル形式を推測しているものと思われます。

ただし、元の拡張子は異なっても中身の特徴が似ている場合には誤判定されるようなケースも当然あります。
.mov と .mp4 の場合であれば、以下のような話のようです。

[MOVとMP4 | 動画ファイル形式](https://www.cloudflare.com/ja-jp/learning/video/mov-vs-mp4/)

> MP4ファイルと同様に、MOV動画はMPEG-4コーデックでエンコードされています。

また、実際にファイルを開く場合についてもソフト側の実装次第にはなります。
例えばメディアプレーヤーの VLC であれば、間違った拡張子のファイルを開こうとすると

「拡張子が間違っているので、ファイル名を修正するか、そのまま再生するか」

を聞かれたはずです。

Comment: 試したソフトウェアは VLC です。「拡張子が間違っているので」とは聞かれなかったのですが、MP4、MOVいずれも再生サポートをしているから聞かれなかったのか、あるいは本当に拡張子が間違っていなかったのか、が私には分かりませんでした。